# Creating Select Options With Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Hay everyone need a bit of help Because i'm new to coding.

I've created a column in my movies table called quality and i want to creating a smarty select option list that would contain 3 options.

```
DVD
TS
CAM
```

So how would i create a smartys select option list and how would i assign the 3 options to the option list.

Here is a example of 1 of my option list looks like.

```
<select name="languages[<?php print($counter); ?>]" id="languages_<?php print($counter); ?>">
<?php 
foreach($language_options as $lang_key => $code){
print("<option value\"{$code}\"");
if (isset($languages[$key]) && $languages[$key]==$code) print(" selected=\"selected\"");
print(">{$code}</option>\n");
}
?>
</select>
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to output a select element or write some sort of smarty helper?

Comment: output a select element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty has a neat little feature for it called `html_options` [(docs)](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl). Basically it's used like this:

```
{html_options name=yournameforit options=$language_options selected=$code)}
```

In your example you're writing in phtml, which got me confused as Smarty has it's own syntax (imho, a lot prettier than phtml). I hope that helps.